# Git Squash Cherry-Picked Commits

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-cherry-pick

Here is the scenario, I have two feature branches like below

```
Feature_List                Feature_API
   \                           \    
    F-G-H-I-J-K                 L-M-N-O-P-Q
```

I have created a new branch from `Feature_API` and cherry-picked all the commits from `Feature_List` and add my changes into this new branch, now when i create PR on github i see all the cherry-picked commits which is obvious. What i want is that my PR should only show my commits not the cherry-picked commits.

What i want is to retain all changes from `Feature_List` and my own new commits in my new branch but i don't want to show cherry-picked commits on PR. The problem is PR shows a long(cherry-picked + my new commits) diff which is want to avoid.

Is this possible and How?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want? Do you only want commits L-M-N-O-P-Q (the original contents of Feature_API) and the corresponding changes from those commits, in the PR, or do you want all the changes from both branches but you want them as one set of commits somehow? I'm not sure what you really want the result to be here?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to not have the cherry-picked commits show in the GitHub pull request.  The good news is that GitHub is doing the right thing by showing the reviewer these cherry-picked commits.  The reason is that your cherry-picked commits are actually *new* commits in the `Feature_API` branch.  As you may have noticed, there can be merge conflicts during a cherry pick in Git because you are essentially re-committing the commits from the `Feature_List` branch.

Since the cherry picked commits are effectively new, GitHub (and Git) cannot distinguish them from any other commit you make in your feature branch.

Comment: Actually the problem is on PR reviewers will see a long(cherry-picked + my own commits) diff and this is what i want to avoid.